# How to delegate mail & calendar for more than one org (i.e. across GAL)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

I've got two different companies both on Office 365. I've hired an assistant in one company, but I want her to manage my mail and calendar from the other company too. Looks like I can't directly delegate across domains/orgs/GALs (Global Address Lists).

So... Is there a way to do with without creating a full licensed user in the second organisation? This is less about saving $5/m and more about reducing her need to log in and juggle different accounts for her self on top of mine. Something like a forwarding identity or something like that?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/microsoft-365-inter-tenant-collaboration?view=o365-worldwide

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD administrators can invite users from other Azure AD tenants to be part of their directory. Step by step guidance for your reference: [Cross-tenant Collaboration with Connected Organizations and Azure AD Entitlements!](https://www.undocumented-features.com/2021/01/26/cross-tenant-collaboration-with-connected-organizations-and-azure-ad-entitlements/)

Comment: Wicked, thanks. Going to check that out